# Multiupload function not send many file to serwer

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
controller:
    public function uploadFiles()
        {
            if (isset($_FILES['file']) && count($_FILES['file']['name']) > 0) {
                $acceptFormat = array(
                    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
                    'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
                    'png' => 'image/png'
                );

                $folder = "system";
                $destinationFilePath = "../" . $this->_config->upload_catalog_name . "" . $folder;    

                $nazwy = array();
                for ($i = 0; $i <= count($_FILES['file']['name']) + 1; $i++) {
                    $newFileName = $this->uploadFile1($_FILES['file'][$i], $destinationFilePath, true, "FILE_SYSTEM_CONFIG", 0, $acceptFormat);
                }

            }
        }

 function:   
    private function uploadFile1(array $filesArray, string $destinationFilePath, bool $fileValidation = true, string $fileType, int $category = 0, array $acceptFormat):string
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= count($filesArray['name']) + 1; $i++) {


                    try {
                        if (
                            !isset($filesArray['error'][$i]) ||
                            is_array($filesArray['error'][$i])
                        ) {
                               throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
                        }

                        switch ($filesArray['error'][$i]) {
                            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                                break;
                            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                                throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
                            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                                throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
                            default:
                                throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
                        }

                        if ($filesArray['size'][$i] > 1000000000) {
                             throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
                        }

                        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filesArray['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                        if (!in_array($ext, array_keys($acceptFormat)) && $fileValidation == true) {
                            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
                        }

                        $mime = mime_content_type($filesArray['tmp_name'][$i]);
                        if (!in_array($mime, array_values($acceptFormat)) && $fileValidation == true) {
                            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid mime format.');
                        }

                        require_once $this->_config->function_path . "RandomFileName.php";
                        $pathTmpName = pathinfo($filesArray['name'][$i]);
                        $fileExtension = strtolower($pathTmpName['extension']);

                        $randomName = randomFileName(60);

                        $newFileName = $randomName . "." . $fileExtension;

                        if (!file_exists($destinationFilePath)) {
                            mkdir($destinationFilePath, 0777);
                        }
                        if (!file_exists($destinationFilePath . "/thumbs")) {
                            mkdir($destinationFilePath . "/thumbs", 0777);
                        }

                        if (!move_uploaded_file($filesArray['tmp_name'][$i], $destinationFilePath . "/" . $newFileName)) {
                            throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
                        } else {
                            return $newFileName;
                        }

                    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                        return "";
                    }
            }
        }
```

I need a universal function to send files to a server in php. It can be 1 file - and it can be 10 at a time.

At the moment I send 1 file to me, despite sending eg 5 files.

As a result of this function I want to get a new file name on the server.
To do this I made such a call:

```
for ($ i = 0; $ i <= count ($ _ FILES ['file'] ['name']) + 1; $ i ++) {
                         $ newFileName = $ this-> uploadFile1 ($ _ FILES ['file'] [$ i], $ destinationFilePath, true, "FILE_SYSTEM_CONFIG", 0, $ acceptFormat);
                     }
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

My incoming data:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => X+T+rcffQvCG67MuqR49Vg.jpg
            [1] => X1pHOaBFRtGyXrA0FoDBVg.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php2fuLup
            [1] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpZIoKbH
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1965954
            [1] => 1557849
        )

)
```

Comment: Are you using any MVC framework?

Comment: MVC - my framework

Comment: I have updated my answer please chek once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload multiple file using php function

```
 //controller:
    public function uploadFile()
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['file']) && count($_FILES['file']['name']) > 0) {
            $acceptFormat = array(
                'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
                'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
                'png' => 'image/png'
            );

            $folder = "system";
            $destinationFilePath = "../" . $this->_config->upload_catalog_name . "" . $folder;
            $resultArray = uploadFiles($_FILES,$acceptFormat,$destinationFilePath);    
        }
    }

    //function :
     function uploadFiles($filesArray,$acceptFormat,$destinationFilePath){
      $result = array();
      foreach ($filesArray as $key => $file)
      {
        for($i=0; $i<count($file['name']); $i++){
          $temp = array();
          $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
          if (!in_array($ext, array_keys($acceptFormat))) {
              $temp['newFileName'] = $file['name'][$i];
              $temp['error'] = 'Invalid file format.';
              // return error if invalid format with original file name and continue upload next file 
          }else if ($file['size'][$i] > 1000000000) 
          {
              $temp['newFileName'] = $file['name'][$i];
              $temp['error'] = 'Exceeded filesize limit.';
              // return error if Exceeded filesize limit with original file name and continue upload next file 
          }else {

              $tempData=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
              $tempData=str_replace("-", "", $tempData);
              $tempData=str_replace(":", "", $tempData);
              $tempData=str_replace(" ", "", $tempData);
              $newFileName = $destinationFilePath.$tempData.$file['name'][$i]."." . $ext;
              $sourcePath = $file['tmp_name'][$i];
              if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$newFileName))
              {
                $temp['newFileName']=$newFileName;
                $temp['error'] = '';
                //upload file successfully and return new file name; 
              }else{
                $temp['newFileName'] = $file['name'][$i];
                $temp['error'] = 'Failed to move uploaded file.';

              }
          }

          $result[] = $temp;
        }
      }
      return $result;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working :(

Now I have this code:

```
$acceptFormat = array(
                'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
                'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
                'png' => 'image/png'
            );

            $folder = "system";
            $destinationFilePath = "../" . $this->_config->upload_catalog_name . "" . $folder;
$resultArray = $this->uploadFiles123($_FILES,  $destinationFilePath, true, "FILE_SYSTEM_CONFIG", 0, $acceptFormat);


 public function uploadFiles123(array $filesArray, string $destinationFilePath, bool $fileValidation = true, string $fileType, int $category = 0, array $acceptFormat)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($filesArray as $file)
        {
            $temp = array();
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if (!in_array($ext, array_keys($acceptFormat)) && $fileValidation == true) {
                $temp['newFileName'] = $file['name'];
                $temp['error'] = 'Invalid file format.';


                $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                $txt = "filename: ".$file['name']."    \n";
                fwrite($myfile, $txt);
                $txt = file_put_contents('newfile1.txt', print_r($file, true));
                fwrite($myfile, $txt);
                fclose($myfile);



                // return error if invalid format with original file name and continue upload next file
            }else if ($file['size'] > 10000000000)
            {
                $temp['newFileName'] = $file['name'];
                $temp['error'] = 'Exceeded filesize limit.';
                // return error if Exceeded filesize limit with original file name and continue upload next file
            }
            else if(is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])){
                require_once $this->_config->function_path . "RandomFileName.php";
                $randomName = randomFileName(60);
                $newFileName = $randomName . "." . $ext;

                if (!file_exists($destinationFilePath)) {
                    mkdir($destinationFilePath, 0777);
                }

                if(move_uploaded_file($newFileName,$destinationFilePath))
                {
                    $temp['newFileName']=$newFileName;
                    $temp['error'] = '';
                    //upload file successfully and return new file name;
                }else{
                    $temp['newFileName'] = $file['name'];
                    $temp['error'] = 'Failed to move uploaded file.';

                }
            }
            $result[] = $temp;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

I added a record to the DEBUG file.

In the file newfile.txt, I have:

```
filename: Array    
598
```

In the file newfile1.txt, I have:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => %6qdJvzqS1OTnJATyo8lZQ.jpg
            [1] => %7OFkadgRPOYWsjcvFeeuQ.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpSJK7LM
            [1] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpyhXxrY
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1636910
            [1] => 2094860
        )

)
```